# Intentando recoger una segunda entidad a partir de su ID en JSON con POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, postman

Tengo 2 entidades, una es `User` y la otra `Absences`, y estoy intentando hacer **POST** para crear una ausencia relacionada con un `User` concreto, su "dueño". La ausencia se crea correctamente con el campo `Date` y el campo `String comment`, pero no logro recoger al usuario a través de su id con el JSON de la petición. No sé si me equivoco en formular el JSON o el problema está en la lógica de java-spring que he construido.
He tratado varias maneras, como pasar por `@Requestbody` solo `Absence` y que el service se encargue de los parámetros de `Absence` y `User` a través de `absence.getStudent()` para ver si recogía la relación directamente, que yo creo que quizás sería lo más lógico, pero tampoco funciona... Ando atascado ya..

```
@Entity
public class Absence {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int id;
    @Nullable
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private Date dateMissing; 

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String comment; 

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @JoinColumn (name="student_id", nullable = false)
    private MyAppUser userStudent;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class MyAppUser {

    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String id;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String firstName;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String lastName;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String email;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private char gender;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private int age;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String portrait;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @ManyToOne
    private Seat seat;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)    
    @ManyToOne
    private Absence userAbsence;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name="rol_id")
    private Role role;

    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Date lastLogin;

    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Absence.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Absence> absences = new ArrayList <Absence>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Course.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    public List <Course> courses = new ArrayList <Course>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = UserExercice.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <UserExercice> userExercices = new ArrayList <UserExercice>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Emails.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Emails> emails = new ArrayList <Emails>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="myAppUser")
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<UserIteration> userIterations;
```

**MyAppUser Repository**

```
public interface MyAppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<MyAppUser, String>{

    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByLastName(String lastName);
    public List<MyAppUser> findByGender(char gender);
    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByRoleId(int roleId);

    Optional <MyAppUser> findOneById(String id );

    MyAppUser findUserById(String id );
}
```

**Controller**

```
    //Create absence by student id
    @PostMapping("/api/students/absences")
    public Absence createAbsence(@RequestBody Absence absence, MyAppUser userStudent) {
        return absencesService.createAbsence(absence, userStudent); 
        //return absencesService.createAbsence(absence, absence.getUserStudent().getId())
       //-->Usando solo Absence como RequestBody! Hay que tener en cuenta 4 cambios pequeños en Service claro está...
    }
```

**Service**

```
    public Absence createAbsence(Absence absence, MyAppUser userStudent) {

        String studentId = userStudent.getId(); 
        //absence.getUserStudent().getId();
        Absence absenceCreated = new Absence();
        userStudent = myAppUserRepository.findUserById(studentId);

        absenceCreated.setComment(absence.getComment());
        absenceCreated.setDateMissing(absence.getDateMissing());
        absenceCreated.setUserStudent(userStudent);

        myAbsenceRepository.save(absenceCreated);
        return absenceCreated;
    }
```

**JSON in POSTMAN**

```
{
    "userStudent": {
        "student_id":"58a55a41-04cc-4007-a322-e7bb969e626b"
    },
    "dateMissing": "1574541388697",
    "comment": "prueba"
}
```

**POSTMAN  me devuelve lo siguiente:**

```
{
    "id": 485,
    "dateMissing": 1574541388697,
    "comment": "prueba",
    "userStudent": null
}
```

Soy un novato en Spring y sus anotaciones, no me lo tengan en cuenta ^^

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno intenta corregir en tu JSON IN POSTMAN : Reemplaza "student_id" por "id"

```
{
    "userStudent": {
        "id":"58a55a41-04cc-4007-a322-e7bb969e626b"
    },
    "dateMissing": "1574541388697",
    "comment": "prueba"
}
```

Si no funciona podrías intentar crear una clase aparte que sirva para el cuerpo del post:

```
public class CreaAbsenceIn {
    private String idStudent;
    private Date dateMissing; 
    private String comment; 
}
```

Y tu JSON IN POSTMAN seria asi:

```
{
    "idStudent":"58a55a41-04cc-4007-a322-e7bb969e626b"
    "dateMissing": "1574541388697",
    "comment": "prueba"
}
```

Y luego capturas los datos desde la clase CreaAbsenceIn y creas la entidad Absence.

Espero esta respuesta te encamine a lo que buscas. Pero en realidad hay mejoras formas de realizar lo que buscas de maneras mas ordenada y mas desacoplado.

Comment: lo he logrado con el cambio en JSON! Eso si, funciona con la parte de código que he dejado comentada en el Controller, recogiendo sólo como RequestBody la Absence. Muchas gracias!